# Avoid regex to capture contents of string (between quotes)

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm using the following regex to capture an array of string that follows certain conditions (e.g.: it's not prepended by some letter or number, and just contains strings surrounded by single or double quotes):

```
/^?[ =>]\[(('|")[^('|")\s]*('|")(, ?)?)+\]/
```

It should capture

```
["bla", "ble", "blo"]
```

However, it should not capture that, if it's part of a string between (single or double) quotes:

```
'["bla", "ble", "blo"]'
```

What should I add to avoid capturing those unwanted case?

Comment: Is this part of data in some standard format, e.g. JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a negative lookbehind/lookahead expression to your pattern:

`(?<!['])(?!['])(\[(('|")[^('|")\s]*('|")(, ?)?)+\])`

Worked for me when testing, but it may depend on your regex engine.